# What can I do to alleviate hip/groin pain on the upstroke?

Tags: exercise, stretching, pain, bicycling

I used to be able to ride my bike for miles and do spin classes with no problems. I stopped when I started working a graveyard shift. It entailed sitting for hours on end. I did this for a few years. I am no longer able to ride due to severe hip/groin pain, primarily on the up stroke. Do you know of any specific beginner exercises/stretches that I can ease into to start alleviating this problem?

Comment: A cyclist I am not; but, I thought you were supposed to drive through 12-6 in the pedal stroke not pull up from 6 to 12. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the pain in your hip is coming from your hip-flexors.

This group is comprised of the: Illiopsoas; Sartorius; and Rectus Femorus.
Their purpose is to: Flex your hip joint; Flex your trunk forward; Pull your thigh upward; and to help stabilize your lower body (at the pelvis).

[image: This images shows how your weight should be distributed for a hip-flexor stretch...]

[image: While this image shows an alternate form that also forces that weight more into your hip because it forces a fixed point (the floor) that the other does not.] This picture doesn't do a great job of showing the weight distribution, though. Or... Maybe the drawing just has *really* tight hip-flexors

The following 2 links have more in depth descriptions with videos to describe the basic stretch (as it can be hard to conceptualize via images). *Some info is repeated*

[Hip-Flexor Videos 1](http://www.fitbodyhq.com/fitness/12-great-stretches-for-tight-hip-flexors/)

[Hip-Flexor Videos 2](http://www.theptdc.com/2015/11/why-doing-hip-flexor-stretches-may-not-loosen-and-open-up-the-hips/)